# OpenSolaris on EC2: make better use of ephemeral drives?

Tags: amazon-ec2, opensolaris

By default when booting an `m1.xlarge` EC2 instance of an OpenSolaris image you're given 1.6T of drive space across 4 ephemeral devices. This is auto-configured as follows:

```
~# zpool status

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    mnt         ONLINE       0     0     0
      c7d1p0    ONLINE       0     0     0
      c7d2p0    ONLINE       0     0     0
      c7d3p0    ONLINE       0     0     0
      c7d4p0    ONLINE       0     0     0
```

What I'd like to do is to change this so that on boot the disk structure is something like the following:

```
    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    mnt         ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1    ONLINE       0     0     0
        c7d1p0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        c7d2p0  ONLINE       0     0     0
    logs        ONLINE       0     0     0
      c7d3p0    ONLINE       0     0     0
    cache
      c7d4p0    ONLINE       0     0     0
```

... onto which I will, on boot, load data from an S3 store.

If I create the above structure and then re-image the machine, subsequent boots from this new AMI fail, either silently (as in, terminating before booting successfully) or fail to respond (once booted they I can't access via SSH or by any other means). Console output is empty in both these instances, except occasionally when there's a complaint about the devices.

**Is what I'm trying to achieve possible?** I'm assuming I'm simply missing the correct `--block-device-mapping` argument when using `ec2-bundle-image` but there's very little information on Google relating to this subject.